# Mock deeper classes/interfaces with Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

Any example I found about mocking with Mockito works similar to this (these are just codesnipets):

Given:

```
public interface MyInterface {
  public String doWhatever();
}

public class MyClass {
  @Autowired
  MyInterface myInterface;

  public String doSomething() {
    return myInterface.doWhatever();
  }
}
```

Mocking:

```
@Mock
MyInterface myInterfaceMock;

@InjectMocks
MyClass myClass;

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    when(myInterfaceMock.doWhatever()).thenReturn("foo");

    String result = myClass.doSomething();
    ...
}
```

However, when introducing a second class, using a deeper level:

```
public class MyOtherClass {
    @Autowired
    MyInterface myInterface;

    public MyInterface getMyInterface() {
        return myInterface;
    }
}
```

class structure for deeper mocking is always done like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    MyOtherClass myOtherClass = new MyOtherClass();

    public MyOtherClass getOtherClass() {
        return myOtherClass;
    }
}

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    given(myClass.getOtherClass().getMyInterface().doSomething()).willReturn("bar");        

    String result = myClass.getOtherClass().getMyInterface().doSomething();
}
```

See this deep stub example for more [information](https://idodevjobs.wordpress.com/2015/04/09/mockito-deep-stubs-example/)

However, this doesn't reflect the class structure I'm supposed to test. The given structure is as follows:

```
public interface MyInterface {
  public String doWhatever();
}

public class MyOtherClass {
  @Autowired
  MyInterface myInterface;

  public String doOtherThing() {
    return myInterface.doWhatever();
  }
}

public class MyClass {
  MyOtherClass myOtherClass = new MyOtherClass();

  public String doSomething() {
    return myOtherClass().doOtherThing();
  }
}
```

Now, I want to mock it similar to this:

```
@Mock
MyInterface myInterfaceMock;

@InjectMocks
MyClass myClass;

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    when(myInterfaceMock.doWhatever()).thenReturn("foo");

    String result = myClass.doSomething();
    ...
}
```

Of course, this does not work, since the mock has to be injected in MyOtherClass and not in MyClass. However, if I inject it to MyOtherClass, I do not have an instance of MyClass.

EDIT:

The cause which lead me to this question is, that I'm supposed to do microservice level testing. May be, I have the wrong approach. I may as well test unit test MyClass by mocking MyOtherClass and unit test MyOtherClass by mocking MyInterface.

So, here is a little more detail about the given microservices:

REST-API -> SomeCode -> SomeOtherCode -> Other-REST-API

Out code covers the REST-API, SomeCode and SomeOtherCode. Other-REST-API is third pary, like Google, mobile service providers, etc.

Now, I'm able to test the REST-API using MockMVC and mocking SomeCode. And I'm able to unit test SomeOtherCode by mocking the Other-REST-API. However, my goal is to test the whole chain by using MockMVC, doing some parameter variations and mocking the Other-TEST-API, to see how SomeCode and SomeOtherCode behaves.

Comment: i updated my solution, it would be just great to get some feedback, if that is what you are looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So What is happening is when the `@InjectMocks` mocks is looking to Autowired things inside `MyClass` to inject, `MyClass` does not have any so it does not find any.

I suspect this would work if `MyOtherClass` was `@Autowired`, however you may need to do `@InjectMocks` for your `MyOtherClass` too.

Comment: Yes, you were right. I changed it to @Autowired. Now, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Base on your update:
you should maybe take a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html - here you can see how you can run an integration test. You can either provide your own spring-xml

```
@ContextConfiguration("/test-config.xml")
public class XmlApplicationContextTests {
    // class body...
}
```

or a class within the test for spring configuration.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class ConfigClassApplicationContextTests {
    // class body...
}
```

Additionally you can define mocks and spys for xml with

```
<bean id="spyService" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="spy">
    <constructor-arg ref="service"/>
</bean>
<bean id="mockService" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock"> 
    <constructor-arg value="your.Service" /> 
</bean>
```

or for the configuration

```
@Configuration
static class TestConfig {
    @Bean
    Service serviceMock() {
        return mock(Service.class);
    }
    @Bean
    Service serviceSpy() {
        return spy(new Service());
    }
}
```

But actually that is how you do integration tests with spring.

You also need to provide the correct UnitTestRunner in this case the SpringJUnitRunner. and you should end up with something like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnitRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class MyClassComponentTest {
    @Autowired
    MyInterface myInterfaceMock;

    @Autowired
    MyClass myClass;

    @Configuration
    static class TestConfig {
        @Bean
        MyClass myClass() {
            return new MyClass();
        }
        @Bean
        MyOtherClass myOtherClass() {
            return new MyOtherClass();
        }
        @Bean
        MyInterface myInterfaceMock() {
            return mock(MyInterface.class);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        when(myInterfaceMock.doWhatever()).thenReturn("foo");

        String result = myClass.doSomething();
        ...
    }
}
```

old answer

> The question is: "Do actually want to unittest?"
>
> Because when you are unittesting, you simply do not care what is
>   happening within `MyOtherClass`. You would simply mock MyOtherClass,
>   and write an own Unittest for `MyOtherClass` where you mock
>   `MyInterface`.
>
> The other problem i see in your example is, that you are never
>   instantiate an object of your Class `MyOtherClass` and that one is
>   never injected into your `MyClass`-Object, so this could actually not
>   work

Comment: Yes, thanx. This comes pretty close. However, looking at my example, the instance of MyInterface in class MyOtherClass is not set, automatically. I had to set it with ReflectionTestUtils.setField(myOtherClass, "myInterface", myIntefaceMock), explicitly.